# Bluetooth communication between iOS and Mac application

Tags: ios, bluetooth

It seems that GameKit can only support the bluetooth communication between iOS devices but not the mac. I want to write a iOS app to talk to a Mac app via bluetooth. Is there any Api that I can use for that? Thanks!

Comment: sza:Did you get any API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using only the public API. May be coming in future, but not now.